# How to prepare clipboard content in Java so that C# application accepts it with Clipboard.ContainsData("Xml Spreadsheet")

Tags: java, c#, xml, excel

I want to prepare clipboard content in Java application and then paste it to C# application. The problem is that C# app seem not to accept data if it was copied to clipboard from any application other than Excel.

C# sources contain following "check" responsible for not accepting plaintext clipboard content:

```
Clipboard.ContainsData("XML Spreadsheet")
```

My question is: how should I set clipboard content in Java (by implementing Transferable and/or defining DataFlavor) in such a way that C# application would recognize it as "XML Spreadsheet"?

Comment: If you want to create communication between two (or more) apps on the same local machine you should better use [Named Pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I'm using standard "system clipboard clipboard" feature in GUI applications: users copy data from Excel and paste to C# app. I want them to be able to copy data from Java application. This is not a usecase for NamedPipes, I'm afraid.

Comment: Oh, i get it. Yeah, NamedPipes gonna be useless here. What if you try in your Java app to define `DataFlavor` for clipboard contents like `new DataFlavor("text/xml", "XML Spreadsheet")` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to follow this path; I just can't find reliable source of xml schema/specification for xml that would be "acceptable" by C# app (since I need to push my tabular data into xml somehow).

Comment: The XML schema can by found by searching for "XML Spreadsheet Reference" on docs.micsoft.com. (Most search engines have a way to limit the search to a specific url; e.g. for Google that would be entering site:learn.microsoft.com as one of the search terms.) I don't know whether adding "XML Spreadsheet" to the DataFlavor as human-readable name will work though.